# Python regex parsing string containing braced items

Tags: python, regex

So I have a set of strings which look like:

```
Callable {option-1} {option-2} {option-3} {option-n}
Callable
Callable {option-1}
```

There may be none or n options.

What I want to do is to parse out the options from this string in a list (`[option-1, option-2, option-3, option-n]`), or `None` if there were no braced options. What is the best way of doing it? At present I do lots of `split('{')` and then strip/clean the output. This feels very ugly.

What is the clean(est) method for doing this?

Comment: Presumably the option text itself doesn't contain braces?

Comment: No indeed, the option just is an alphanumeric string without braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
re.findall(r'{([^}]+)}', inputtext)
```

This pattern matches anything that isn't a closing brace as the option text; alternatively, you can use word characters, digits and dashes:

```
re.findall(r'{([\w\d-]+)}', inputtext)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> samples = '''\
... Callable {option-1} {option-2} {option-3} {option-n}
... Callable
... Callable {option-1}
... '''
>>> for line in samples.splitlines():
...     print re.findall(r'{([^}]+)}', line)
... 
['option-1', 'option-2', 'option-3', 'option-n']
[]
['option-1']
```

This produces *lists* of matches; no matches results in an empty list.

Comment: Great thanks! In terms of grabbing the callable string, what is the best way of doing this to encompass both callables with and without options?

Comment: @jvc26: is it always at the start of a string? Just split on the first whitespace would be easiest: `line.partition(' ')[0]` would get you anything up to the first space, or the whole line if there is no space.

Comment: It is, but sometimes the string has spaces in it. I thought about splitting on '{', if this fails, then take the whole string.

Comment: @jvc26: `line.partition('{')[0].rstrip()` will do just fine then, because that call never fails, instead returns the input string plus two empty strings (one for the non-existing delimiter, the other for the non-existing tail).

Comment: @jvc26: the `.rstrip()` is there to remove the whitespace between the name and the curly brace, if there is any.